# split column of list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames. Each data frame has only one column with data separated "\t". Name of the column is different for different data frames. I want to split the column and provide names for the new columns.

```
list.df <- c(df1,df2,df3....df1000)
df1
$`000004.ame`
[1] 0.0\t0.00\t12.1\t1.0\t14.01\t1       2.0\t0.00\t13.9\t-0.2\t14.02\t1     
[3] 4.0\t-0.00\t13.2\t0.2\t14.01\t1      6.0\t0.00\t12.8\t0.0\t14.02\t1      
[5] 8.0\t0.00\t13.7\t0.0\t14.02\t1

other data frames are similar with different column names
```

I got it for one data frame but I want to apply to list of data frames

```
 colnames(X) <- "text"
 library(splitstackshape)
 X <- cSplit(as.data.frame(X),"text","\t")
 colnames(X) <- c("T","I")
```

How can I apply this to a list of data frames?
Please guide me regarding this

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your data

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Use `lapply` to iterate over the list, something like `lapply(list.df, function(i) {d1 <- data.frame(text = i); cSplit(d1, 'text', '\t')})` (untested)

Comment: thank you. it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)

# Creating similiar dfs

vec1 <- c("0.0\t0.00\t12.1\t1.0\t14.01\t1","0.0\t0.00\t12.1\t1.0\t14.01\t1" 
,"0.0\t0.00\t12.1\t1.0\t14.01\t1","0.0\t0.00\t12.1\t1.0\t14.01\t1")
df1 <- as.data.frame(vec1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- df1

list.df <- c(df1,df2)

# Looping over this list with lapply
# Using stringrs str_split instead of splitstackshape


 list.splitted.dfs <- lapply(list.df, function(x) unlist(str_split(x[1], 
 "\t")))

 # Output from above is a list, need to bind it together
 new <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, list.splitted.dfs))
 > newdf
 V1   V2   V3  V4    V5    V6
 1 0.0 0.00 12.1 1.0 14.01  1
 2 0.0 0.00 12.1 1.0 14.01  1
```